# FormCollection is null on Kendo Grid sorting postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using Asp.Net MVC Kendo Grid. While doing sorting, I am not getting anything on FormCollection at controller. But all other postbacks other than kendo controllers sends FormCollection to the controller. Please advice.

Comment: show some code so we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Read method on Kendo Grid can be used for doing anything related to Kendo Grid like Sorting or Paging etc..Even postback is not required when doing sorting on Kendo Grid. In new dll of Kendo,
everythin can be done without doing postback.

Answer (score 2):

If your DataSource is set to use HTTP GET then the FormCollection would be empty.
Inside your MVC controller you could use `var x = Request["paramName"];` instead, which would get you values sent to the server whether GET or POST was used.